# Counting/totaling rows in a create view statement, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, view, workbench

I have a database and I want to create a view that allows the person to invoke the view name to see the "year, semester, credits", for the view. What I want to do is have it give me the year, then the semester and then the total credits taken per semester.

So, it should return a result if I have 2 students in spring 2010, and they took 2 classes each at 3 credit hours per class at a total of 12 credits, and so on and so fourth.

EX. '2010     Spring   12'

```
CREATE VIEW tot_cred26
AS
SELECT DISTINCT year, semester, COUNT(credits)
FROM course INNER JOIN takes;
```

Thanks again guys, super new to SQL and you all have been really helpful! :)

Comment: Use `GROUP BY`, not `DISTINCT`.

Comment: And use `SUM`, not `COUNT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` to combine rows for each set of values. And since you want the total credits, you should use `SUM`; `COUNT` just counts the number of rows. And your `INNER JOIN` needs an `ON` clause to specify how the two tables are related; I'm assume there's a `courseid` column in both tables.

```
CREATE VIEW tot_cred26 AS
SELECT year, semester, SUM(credits) as total_credits
FROM course AS c
INNER JOIN takes as t ON t.courseid = c.courseid
GROUP BY year, semester
```

Comment: I wish i could up vote, but im so darn new it doesn't let me!

Comment: hey, quick question,  you said that my inner join needed an "on" clause to specify how the tables are related…is that why i need an on clause only, or are there more reasons, or could i use a "where clause?" im trying to find anything that explains the "on" clause but its no luck.

Comment: Except for LEFT JOIN, it's equivalent to do it in WHERE. But doing it in the ON clause is preferred, because it shows which conditions are used for joining the table versus those that are used for filtering data.

Comment: cool, thanks! why can't all books and websites just say that? they have to use 12 paragraphs and then they end up not explaining a thing!

Answer (score 0):

Below Code may solve the problem:

```
CREATE VIEW tot_cred26
AS
SELECT year, semester, COUNT(credits) total_credits
FROM course INNER JOIN takes
group by year, semester
;
```